# How do I access file from Sub Domain using the Main Domain host?

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

How do I access file from Sub Domain using the Main Domain host?

Let say I uploaded an image on my subdomain as what's shown below

https://subdomain.example.com/pic/image21343.png

How can I access this image using the main domain host?

For example: https://example.com/pic/image21343.png

Comment: I dont get what you mean by access. Could you write more details?

Comment: I just want to pull out the image url that is stored in my sub domain but with main domain host name instead.

Comment: What are `DocumentRoot` locations of subdomain and main domain?

Answer (score -1):

I reckon you want to remove subdomain. You can add something like this to your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Got from [here](http://%20%20%20%20RewriteEngine%20On%20%20%20%20%20RewriteCond%20%25%7BHTTP_HOST%7D%20!%5Esub%5C.domain%5C.com$%20[NC]%20%20%20%20%20RewriteRule%20(.*)%20http://sub.domain.com$1%20[R=301,L])

Comment: No! I am basically asking the same the same question as this guy but the opposite. I want to access sub domain from main domain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704881/accessing-main-domain-folder-from-sub-domain-in-php?rq=1